# Two apps in one apk

Tags: android, xamarin

When I build a single apk and I try to install it on the device two apps are shown instead of one, but neither app opens. What is the cause of this? I just want one only.

Comment: add more details !

Comment: Each launcher intent in the manifest gets an icon in the app grid, so you possibly have two launcher intents there. Not opening can be due to a multitude of issues. Have a look at logcat for any helpful trace.

Comment: You might have multiple `MainLauncher` defined: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/android-manifest

Comment: try to show us what have you tried

Answer (score 3):

No, there's still just one app but you need to tweak your Manifest file as apparently you have two activities with

```
<intent-filter>    
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />    
            </intent-filter>
```

Remove this filter from activity *you do not* want to be your entry point.